# Using a compiler specified on the command line or automatically detected

Tags: haskell, null, compiler, tex

Here is part of my build system.

```
guessCompilers :: Options -> IO Options
guessCompilers options =  foldl (>>=) (return options) modifiers where 
  modifiers = 
    [guessMetapost 
     -- guessAsymptote, 
     -- guessTex, 
     -- guessLatex, 
     -- guessXelatex
    ]   
guessMetapost :: Options -> IO Options
guessMetapost opts = if isJust $ optMetaPost opts 
                         then 
                           putStrLn $ printf "using enforced Metapost compiler: %s" (fromJust $optMetaPost opts)
                           >> return opts
                         else do 
                           cc <- compiler Metapost.interface
                           if isJust cc then putStrLn $ printf "found Metapost compiler: %s" (fromJust cc)
                                             else putStrLn "found Metapost compiler: none"
```

Compiler can be spectified by cmd args or can be guessed. But double checking for `Nothing` is not cool in my opinion. Also, I heard `fromJust` is evil. Any suggestions to improve my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern match instead of using `isJust` and `fromJust`. (You could use `maybe` instead of pattern matching, but I think pattern matching is clearer in this case.)

This eliminates the possibility of forgetting to ensure a value is a Just before calling `fromJust` on it.

```
guessMetapost :: Options -> IO ()
guessMetapost opts
   = case optMetaPost opts of
         Just mcc -> putStrLn $ printf "using enforced Metapost compiler: %s" mcc
         Nothing -> do
           cc' <- compiler Metapost.interface
           case cc' of
               Just cc -> putStrLn $ printf "found Metapost compiler: %s" cc
               Nothing -> putStrLn "found Metapost compiler: none"
```

(Your code wasn't consistently returning any options, so I've stripped that bit out.)

Comment: You can also get rid of `putStrLn $ printf ...`, and simply write `printf`. There is an `IO a` instance of [`PrintfType`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html#t:PrintfType).